# Error converting datetime from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
INSERT INTO Restaurants_final (DateField) VALUES ('01/01/2000')
```

This query keeps coming back with Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string. But this method has worked seemlessly for me for years. What am I doing wrong?

DateField is set to a datetime format.

Comment: As a general comment that is applicable to all RDBMS; **never** rely on implicit string to date conversion. _Always_ use either an ANSI literal or convert explicitly to a date. It's clearer to future developers that it's a date column and you avoid problems like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert these dates literal in a language neutral manner, using the format `YYYYMMDD` like this:

```
INSERT INTO Restaurants_final (DateField) VALUES ('20000101')
```

Comment: is there a way to convert this in SQL?

Comment: I mean I am inputting the dates as variables. Is there an inbuilt way to convert them to this format?

Comment: @Max - Sorry, no there isn't, but if you are inserting these values using a front end application, like C# for example you can use the prepared statements, and it will take care of all these formatting and conversion stuff using sqlparamters.